# How to calculate LL(2) lookahead

Tags: parsing, grammar, regex-lookarounds

How can we calculate the 2 lookaheads of a grammar in order to form a LL(2) one? I tried to transform a grammar into LL1 but there were still conflicts. So, I want to test if it is a LL2 grammar